# Is there any tab priority settings in Sugar Pro 6.3.0

Tags: tabs, sugarcrm

I am using sugar pro 6.3.0 but when i redoeder my tabs with the Display Module Tabs and Subpanels option available in Administration tab, the tab like Accounts automatically gets displayed before other tabs even if the Accounts tab is displayed below the other tabs on the Administration»Display Module Tabs and Subpanels as shown below:

[image]

Any idea where to change that priority to see the tabs in the exact order as shown in the Displayed Tabs column in the above figure?

Comment: If you can let me know your Sugar Customer account information, I can get our support team involved here. Thanks!

Comment: For regular user the tabs work normally that they get displayed perfectly as ordered by the administrator. Only for administrator we cant see the exact order, is it the default behaviour?

Comment: You should still be able to order them. Again, if you could ping me directly at jmertic at sugarcrm dot com with your support contract info I could help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click your username at the top, next to 'Log Out'.
Then click the tab 'Advanced'.
In the panel 'Layout Options', you should be able to arrange the order of tabs for the particular user.
Clicking 'Reset User Preferences' button on the same page should also fix it.